# does anyone know why my width is not defined, it seems that i have

Tags: python, nameerror

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

canvas = Canvas(root,width= width,height= height, bg='black')
canvas.pack(pady=20)
width,height=200,200
shape=canvas.create_circle(fill=yellow)

def pressed(event):
    index=random.randrange(0,5)
    x,y=0,0
    if event.char == "a":
        x,y =-10,0
    if event.char == "d":
        x,y =10,0w
    if event.char == "w":
        x,y =0,-10
    if event.char == "s":
        x,y =-0,10
root.bind("",pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

I think I have already defined width and height but I still get the error.This is why i am asking for help. Please answer!! :))

Comment: You define them *after* you try to use them in the call to `Canvas`.

Comment: oh thanks i realise :)). im a newbie so its seems dumb. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use width and height before defining it. Just initialize width and height before using it, and you are good to go.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

width,height=200,200
canvas = Canvas(root,width= width,height= height, bg='black')
canvas.pack(pady=20)
shape=canvas.create_circle(fill=yellow)

def pressed(event):
    index=random.randrange(0,5)
    x,y=0,0
    if event.char == "a":
        x,y =-10,0
    if event.char == "d":
        x,y =10,0w
    if event.char == "w":
        x,y =0,-10
    if event.char == "s":
        x,y =-0,10
root.bind("",pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks to all who helped, i really needed this. didnt expect an answer as its my first question anyway! Have a nice day everyone!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hi, i just ran your code but im getting another error. i will ask another question but this one has been answered .

Comment: Hi, there are quite a few errors. What are you trying to do with your code? A Canvas object doesn't have a "create_circle" method, and your Tk() object is bound to an empty string.

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple WASD game with a circle as the moving object. it's just a prototype but I cant seem to get that working too